# Eigenvalue of an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix with rank 2

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Below is a question from the GATE Exam.

> $\text{Let A be an $n \times n$ real valued square symmetric matrix of rank 2 with}$
> $\text{$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}^2=50$. Consider the following statements}$
>
> $\quad\text{(I) One Eigenvalue must be in $[-5,5]$}$
>
> $\quad\text{(II) The eigenvalue with the largest magnitude must be strictly greater than $5$.}$
>
> $\text{Which of the above statements about eigenvalues of A is/are necessarily CORRECT?}$
>
> $\quad\quad\text{(A) Both I and II}$
>
> $\quad\quad\text{(B) I only}$
>
> $\quad\quad\text{(C) II only}$
>
> $\quad\quad\text{(D) Neither I nor II}$

My attempt:

Let A be $\begin{bmatrix} -5&0\\0&5\\ \end{bmatrix}$ so, it's eigenvalues are -5 and 5. So statement I is true but II is false. So, the answer is B.

I can understand that the questions ask for conditions which are always true for a real values square symmetric matrix of rank 2.

Is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: Your example only shows that II is not necessarily true. You cannot conclude that the answer is B, because you haven't eliminated D as a possible choice.

Answer (score 5):

We are being told that $\|A\|_F^2 =50$ and also $A$ is a real symmetric matrix with rank $2$.

Hence $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 =50$ and we know that the eigenvalues are real.

Suppose all eigenvalues are not in $[-5, 5]$, that is if $|\lambda_i|>5, \forall i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ . Then, $$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 \ge n \min_i \lambda_i^2> 2(5)^2=50.$$

which is a contradiction. Hence $(I)$ is true.

Comment: -What is this $||A||_F^2$ ?

Comment: [Frobenius norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html), basically sum of squares of each element.

Comment: Why do you say "Hence $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 =50$"? What is the theorem behind this conclusion. Please do say it...

Comment: refers to the property of [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)

Comment: Is there a way to solve it, without the support of the theorem? I mean,working from scratch, using concepts of basic linear algebra?

Comment: $\|A\|_F^2 = \|UDU^T\|_F^2=\|D\|_F^2$

Answer (score 2):

Take the matrix$A$ of the form $A= \operatorname{diag} ( 5,5,0,... )$. Then
$\|A\|_F^2 = 50$, but both eigenvalues are in $[-5,5]$. Hence II is not true.

Since $A$ is symmetric, the singular values are the absolute values of the eigenvalues (which are real). Since $A$ has rank 2 there are exactly two non zero
eigenvalues.

Hence $\|A\|_F^2 = \lambda_1^1+\lambda_2^2 = 50$. Hence $\min(\lambda_1^1,\lambda_2^2) \le 25$ and so $\min(|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|) \le 5$
and so $I$ is true.

Hence B is the correct answer.

Comment: Why do you say "Hence $\|A\|_F^2 = \lambda_1^1+\lambda_2^2 = 50$" ? What is the theorem behind the conclusion? Could you please suggest an easy textbook that contains the same ?

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh The Frobenius norm is invariant under orthogonal transformations, so if $A = U^T D U$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $D$ a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, we see that $\|A\|_F^2 = \sum_k \lambda_k^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A = \begin{bmatrix} -5 & 0 \\ 0 & 5  \end{bmatrix}  $  then $\|A\|_{F}^{2}\neq 50.$  If $A $ is a diagonal matrix then $ \|D\| = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n } |d_{i}|$ so $ \|A \|_{F}^{2} = 5$

```
A = [-5,0;0,5];
my = norm(A);
display(my)
my =

 5
```

Also, the eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are the diagonal. And diagnonal matrices triangular matrices. So the eigenvalues are $-5,5$