# $A_{n \times n}$ real valued square symmetric matrix of rank 2 with $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}^2=50$ then one eigenvalue must be in $[-5,5]$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Prove that : *"If $A_{n \times n}$ real valued square symmetric matrix of rank $2$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}^2=50$ then one eigenvalue must be in $[-5,5]$."*

This question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2853116/606943), but the point is that this question was asked in an exam, where a student is supposed to know only the basics and intuition of how linear algebra works.

The answers given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2853116/606943), makes use of theorem, which I have never heard of and is probably out of the scope of the syllabus of the exam in which this question was asked.

So my question is how should one try to approach this question using basic intuition and knowledge of linear algebra (of UG level).

Comment: All three answers to the linked question involve only basic linear algebra. They all use the fact that $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}^2=\operatorname{tr}(AA^T)=\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=\sum_i\lambda_i^2$. I don't think there are easier solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, we'll notice that squaring a matrix "preserves" in a certain way eigenthings, in the sense that if $\lambda$ and $v$ are an eigenvalue and eigenvector for $A$, $\lambda^2$ and $v$ are an eigenvalue and eigenvector for $A^2$:

$Av = \lambda v \Rightarrow A^2v = A(Av) = A(\lambda v) = \lambda Av =\lambda^2v)$

On the other hand, as $A$ is symmetric, $A$ is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues. Because of A being diagonalizable, every eigenvalue geometric and algebraic multiplicity are equal. We notice that $dim(A_0) = dim(kerA) = n - rank(A)$. Thus, $A$ has only $2$ non zero (maybe equal) eigenvalues, that I'll denote $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, $\sum_{i,j =1}^n A_{ij}^2 = tr(A^TA)$. Because of $A$ being real and symetric, $A^T=A$, so $\sum_{i,j =1}^n A_{ij}^2 = tr(A^2)$. Also, recall that for a diagonalizable matrix, $tr(D) =\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$. Because of $A$ being diagonalizable, so is $A^2$ ($A = CDC^{-1} \Rightarrow A^2 = CD(C^{-1}C)DC^{-1} = CD^2C^{-1}$). Then $\sum_{i,j =1}^n A_{ij}^2 = tr(A^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_{A^2i} = \lambda_{Ai}^2 = \lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2$ (because the rest of them are 0)

What remains is up to you (Hint: work BWOC)

Comment: Nice answer. But what means BWOC? :)

Comment: By Way Of Contradiction

Comment: Thanks! I had never heard that before.

Comment: What is $A_0$ here? Please can you say it ?

Comment: Wonderful answer...

Comment: $A_0$ is the proper subspace of the eigenvalue $0$ (the kernel)